# Stream from JMS queue and store in Hive/MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, scala, hive, jms

I have the following setup (that I cannot change) and I'd like some advice from people who have been down that road. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here goes anyway.

- Various JSON messages are placed on a different channels of a JMS queue (Universal Messaging/webMethods).
- Before the data can be stored in relational-style DBs it has to be transformed: renamed, arrays flattened and some structures from nested objects extracted.
- Data has to be appended to MySQL (as a serving layer for a visualization tool) and Hive (for long-term storage).
- We're stuck on Spark 1.4.1 and may move to 1.6.0 in a few months' time. So, structured streaming is not (yet) an option.
- At some point the events will be streamed directly to real-time dashboards, so having something in place that is capable of doing that now would be ideal.
- Ideally coding is done in Scala (because we already have considerable batch-based repo with Spark and Scala), so the minimal requirement is JVM-based.

I've looked at Spark Streaming but it does not have a JMS adapter and as far as I can tell operating on JSON would be done [using a SQLContext instance on the DStream's RDDs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations). I understand that it's possible to write a custom adapter, but then I'm not sure if Spark is still the best/easiest solution. I've also looked at the doc for Samza and Flink but did not find much for JMS and/or JSON, at least not natively.

Apache Camel seems like it might have a substantial set of connectors but I'm not too familiar with it, and I get the impression it does not do the streaming part, 'just' the bit where you connect to various systems. There's also Akka although I get the impression it's more of a replacement for messaging systems and JMS is set.

There is an almost bewildering amount of available tools and I'm at this point at a loss what to look at or what to look out for. What do you recommend based on your experience that I use to pick up the messages, transform, and insert into Hive and MySQL?